# In linux,who can be a root user?

Tags: linux, root

I were using windows but now I am shift to unix like os sucn as linux,fedora .Now I am confused what is root in linux os?Please explain me.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=linux+root

Comment: Thank you ,very useful and informative

Answer (score 2):

Root user is also known as superuser in Linux-based OS. Basically, `root` user is granted all permission to do various task on that system. This includes adding/removing normal user account, managing services, changing ownership of files/folder and many more.

Normally, it is recommended for system administrator to create another normal user account to perform day-to-day operations while `root` account should only use when necessary. Once the system administrator has completed the necessary task, he/she will then revert back to their normal user account immediately. It is because a mistyped of command using root account might lead to wiping all data in the system!

For more information about root, you can visit [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-can-i-log-in-as-root/) and [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/root-account.html). Hope it helps.